# Array 'contains()' check is failing to detect rounded value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append, contains

I have `Double` values which I am using `floor()` to round 0 to 1, and converting other double values to `Integer`. Then, I am using `contains()` to check if the value exists and if not, append them in array. Here is the snippet:

```
let radius = center.distanceFromLocation(location) / 1000
let section = floor(radius) == 0 ? 1 : Int(radius)

if !self.myArray.contains(Int(radius)) {
    self.myArray.append(section)
}
```

The problem is, it's appending different values in `myArray` for '1' and '1 rounded from 0'.

Here is some debugs:

```
(lldb) po myArray
▿ 3 elements
  - [0] : 1
  - [1] : 1 { ... }
  - [2] : 11      // it's working fine for other numbers

(lldb) po myArray[0]
1

(lldb) po myArray[1]
1

(lldb) po myArray[2]
11


(lldb) p myArray[0]
(Int) $R11 = 1

(lldb) p myArray[1]
(Int) $R10 = 1
```

Comment: Please provide actual values for testing.

Comment: It goes like: ' 0, 1, 11 '. 11 is working fine.. However, "1" and "the 1 which rounded from 0" behaves like 2 different values even though both are 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `!self.myArray.contains(Int(radius))` which is wrong in your case.

Lets say the array already contains a `1` and you know are wondering wether to insert `0.3`. `section` becomes `1`, but you check wether or not `Int(radius)` = `0` is contained already which it is not. Then you add the `section` (`1`) again.

Your code should be

```
if !self.myArray.contains(section) {
    self.myArray.append(section)
}
```

Or alternatively use a `Set` which ensures every value is contained at most once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you take Int(radius) which is different for Int(1) and Int(0.45) for example. 
You should try checking if myArray contains section, not Int(radius), because it may lead to the incorrect behaviour that you are experiencing.